# Design Question: Translation Class

Tags: java

I have two objects:

1. `Form`. A form that I populate from a JSP page.
2. `Input`.  An input object for a web service call.

The input object is not suited to use to fill the form fields on my JSP page.

I need to populate the values in the `Input` object based on the values in the `Form` object.  Is any of these options better?

Just Do It.  In my controller, just create an `Input` object and call the Input setters from my controller.

`Form.loadTo(Input target)`.  Implement a method in the `Form` class that takes an `Input` object as a parameter and call the Input setters in the loadTo method.

`Input.loadFrom(Form source)`.  Implement a method in the `Input` class that takes a `Form` object as a parameter and load valus by calling getters from the Form.

`Translator.loadTo(Form source, Input target)`.  Create a third class to encapsulate the translation logic.  This is my preference because it controls the coupling of the the Form and Input classes, but it seems like overkill.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Translator.loadTo()
```

[SRP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle).

Answer (score 0):

```
Form.loadTo()
```

seems to be the most logical.

It doesn't require the third class and looks logical: Input is a part of the form, so the form can know about the input.

In other cases Input knows about the structure that is bigger and contains the Input. It is not logical IMHO.